# R: Plotting a 2D Matrix (RDM) as colored squares

Tags: r, matrix

I've got a 2D Matrix (a Representational Dissimilarity Matrix) containing dissimilarities (numeric values) between 92 images (=> 92x92 matrix). Now I'd like to plot this in an image, displaying the matrix as colored squares where the color depends on the value in the matrix. I.e. it'd be a 2D plot of 92x92 colored squares, representing the matrix' elements. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right place where to ask this. I know two simple solutions:

```
library(raster)    
r <- matrix(rnorm(8464,0,1),nrow=94, ncol=94)
plot(raster(r))
```

or

```
image(r)
```